# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table 'Accountants' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following entity:

```
public class Accountants
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Person Accountant { get; set; }
    public Person AccountantSubstitute { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Person entity:

```
public class Person
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to update my database, I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_Accountants_Person_AccountantSubstituteId' on table 'Accountants'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints. Could not create constraint or index. See previous
>   errors.

If i understand this correct, it will be cycles or multiple casacde paths when you delete a AccountantSubstitute? If so, why and how can I turn off "cascading on delete" in entityframework core for this entity?

I have tried to do something like this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOne("AccountantSubstitute").WithMany().HasForeignKey("AccountantSubstituteId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

But this gives me the error:

```
The navigation property 'AccountantSubstitute' cannot be added to the entity type 'Person' because there is no corresponding CLR property on the underlying type and navigations properties cannot be added to shadow state.'
```

So how can I fix this?

EDIT:

I seem to solve the problem like this:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Accountants>().HasOne(x => x.AccountantSubstitute).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.Id).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

But I can't understand the solution? What is that code doing? I don't understand the "WithMany()".

Comment: This looks like it might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750960/entity-framework-core-how-to-solve-introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause?rq=1

Comment: @FlyingFoX: I don't know on which entity I should turn off the cascading delete..

Comment: With your design theoretically you could have two identical references to the same Person object in an Accountants Row. That could lead to these multiple cascade paths.