# How should I configure relationships between these models with Fluent API?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluent

I'm getting this error **"Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Tasks_Projects_ProjectId' on table 'Tasks' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths"**

Tasks in Project class can be empty and also User can be without TeamId.

```
public class Task {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ProjectId {get; set;}
    public int PerformerId {get; set;}
    public User Performer {get; set;}
}

public class Project {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public int TeamId {get; set;}
    public List<Task> Tasks {get; set;}
    public User Author {get; set;}
    public Team Team {get; set;}
}

public class Team {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class User {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ?TeamId {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar post about this here: [Entity Framework Core: How to solve Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41750960/entity-framework-core-how-to-solve-introducing-foreign-key-constraint-may-cause)

To simplify this I would just capture the id of the user as an int on the projects and tasks (instead of the user entity).

```
public class Task {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ProjectId {get; set;}
    public int PerformerId {get; set;}
}

public class Project {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public int TeamId {get; set;}
    public List<Task> Tasks {get; set;}
    public int Author {get; set;}
    public Team Team {get; set;}
}

public class Team {
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class User {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int ?TeamId {get; set;}
}
```

Ultimately I would opt for a slightly different structure like this:

```
public class Task
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int PerformerID { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
}
```